# How to compare elements between lists of tuples?

Tags: python, list, tuples

```
new_list = [
    ('99', '99', '081589JC', 'Left'),
    ('99', '99', '051184EC', 'Right'),
    ('99', '99', '202020AZ', 'Center')
]

old_list = [
    ('081589JC', '99', '081251CG', 'Center'),
    ('99', '99', '061456JC', 'Left'),
    ('99', '99', '202020AZ', 'Above')
]

add_list = []
deL_list = []

for a in range(len(new_list)):
  if new_list[a][2] not in old_list:
    add_list.append[a]

for d in range(len(old_list)):
  if old_list[d][2] not in add_list:
    deL_list.append(d)

print(add_list)
print(deL_list)
```

add_list should contain the new_list tuples containng '081589JC', and '051184EC'.

deL_list should contain the old_list tuples containing '081251CG', and '061456JC'.

This is what would ideally work, but because we're dealing with tuples, I can't find a way to compare one element against the entire list without doing a case by case scenario that doesn't help the script at all. I have no problem doing the comparison when it's just a singleton tuple and not a whole row of information which is what they represent. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It looks like a job for sets. You can convert those lists into sets and use ``difference`` method

Answer (score 0):

If the value at index 2 within the tuple is what is determining the uniqueness of the tuples in your case, it might be worth storing the tuples in a dictionary.
Something like:

```
new_list = [
    ('99', '99', '081589JC', 'Left'),
    ('99', '99', '051184EC', 'Right'),
    ('99', '99', '202020AZ', 'Center')
]

old_list = [
    ('081589JC', '99', '081251CG', 'Center'),
    ('99', '99', '061456JC', 'Left'),
    ('99', '99', '202020AZ', 'Above')
]

def tuple_list_to_dict(tuple_list, key_index):
    ''' Converts a list of tuples to a dict mapping each tuples' key to the tuple '''
    return {tup[key_index]: tup for tup in tuple_list}

new_dict = tuple_list_to_dict(new_list, 2)
old_dict = tuple_list_to_dict(old_list, 2)

add_list = []
deL_list = []

# we use a set here to make sure we are looping over all the unique keys only once
for key in set(new_dict.keys() + old_dict.keys()):
    if key not in new_dict and key in old_dict:    
        deL_list.append(old_dict[key])
    elif key in new_dict and key not in old_dict:
        add_list.append(new_dict[key])

print(add_list)
print(deL_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, using sets makes it more efficient to find differences and perform `in` checks.

```
new_list = [
    ('99', '99', '081589JC', 'Left'),
    ('99', '99', '051184EC', 'Right'),
    ('99', '99', '202020AZ', 'Center')
]

old_list = [
    ('081589JC', '99', '081251CG', 'Center'),
    ('99', '99', '061456JC', 'Left'),
    ('99', '99', '202020AZ', 'Above')
]

old_keys = {it[2] for it in old_list}
new_keys = {it[2] for it in new_list}
added_keys = new_keys - old_keys
deleted_keys = old_keys - new_keys

add_list = [it for it in new_list if it[2] in added_keys]
del_list = [it for it in old_list if it[2] in deleted_keys]

print(add_list)
print(del_list)
```

Comment: Wow! That's genius how you made use of the set comprehensions like that. I was trying that out myself, but went about it all wrong. Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem. However, if you use the third key as your index, then maybe you should structure your data a bit differently.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for another viable solution, Spencer!

I had to make an adjustment on the for loop since it wasn't working properly on my end.

combined_set = {**new_dict, **old_dict}

for key in combined_set:
    if key not in new_dict and key in old_dict:
        deL_list.append(old_dict[key])
    elif key in new_dict and key not in old_dict:
        add_list.append(new_dict[key])